# Как автоматически выполнить метод при запуске приложения?

Tags: java, spring, развертывание

Всема способами у меня почему-то метод выполняется дважды!

Подскажите другие способы автоматического выполнения метода при старте программы. Или если кто знает, подскажите в чем может быть проблема двойного запуска метода?

Варіант 1:

```
@Service
public class RunJob implements InitializingBean {
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        System.out.println("JOB RUN");
    }
}
```

Варіант 2:

```
public class RunJob {
    @PostConstruct
    public void initRun() {
        System.out.println("JOB RUN");
    }
}
```

Варіант 3:

`mvc-servlet.xml`:

```
<bean id="runJobBean" class="com.java.myproject.util.RunJob" init-method="init"></bean>

public class RunJob {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("JOB RUN");
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблему с двойным запуском метода так и не решил. Но так как у меня метод запускал джоб, я просто сделал проверку запущен ли джоб и таким способом решил мою проблему.

Answer (score 1):

используй init method в XML-описании. а там указываешь какой метод нужно вызвать. 
этот метод должен быть статическим, если не ошибаюсь

Будет вызывться этот метод по имени init по инициализации бина

Comment: <beans>
    <bean id="myBean" class="..." init-method="init"/>
</beans>

Comment: простите, не получается вставить XML в ответ

Comment: Спасибо, пробывал, к сожалению так тоже метод запускается дважды!

Comment: можно описание XML или нотации? значит ты 2 раза инициализируешь его

Comment: Саакя "значит ты 2 раза инициализируешь его" - не понял, почему?

Для XML:
`<bean id="runJobBean" class="com.java.myproject.util.RunJob" init-method="init"></bean>`
Для анотации:
    `@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("RunJob!");
    }`

Comment: ну может у тебя бин еще раз вызывается и инициализаруется в другом бине. хз. 
Скинь лучше всю аннотацию xml и код, который вызываешь

Comment: Метод `init()` Вы указываете и в `init-method="init"`, и аннотируете его одновременно?

Comment: @Tema_Bel, нет! Я пробывал разные способами, но по отдельности.

Comment: Проверьте, что метод `init()` никем не используется, кроме Spring'а

Comment: @Tema_Bel, Не используется. Я его только добавил.

Comment: @Giovanni ну ты выложишь нотации с кодом или будем гадать?

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян отредактировал вопрос, можете посмотреть! И что такое нотации? Возможно вы имели введу аннотации!?

Comment: @ PostConstruct - aннотация для метода, который будет вызван после вызова конструктора бина.
{ <...  init-method="init"></bean> } вызывается после инициализации конструктора
получается, что у тебя 2 sout выводят одни и те же сообщения, сначала init-method после определения контекста и еще раз после @ PostConstruct
вот и получается, что у тебя 2 раза все выполняется. 

Используй либо XML, либо аннотации

Comment: @Цовак Саакян, Вы не поняли, как я уже писал я использовал один из вариантов за раз!